Получение данных из JSON объекта
Задача взять из столбца tOnline передать фронтенду значение столбца т.е 90.

Бэкенд:
const express = require('express')
const TelegramApi = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
const mysql = require('mysql2')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002
const app = express()
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "31.31.198.112",
  user: "u2642045_jahon",
  database: "u2642045_dragonapp",
  password: "joha_003"
})
app.get('/back4',(req, res) =>{
    connection.execute("SELECT `tOnline` FROM `stage`", (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          return;
        }
          res.json({
          online: results[0].tOnline
        });
      });
})
app.post('/chatback', (req, res) => {
  let data = [req.body.Hunters]
  connection.query("UPDATE `stage` SET `tOnline`= ? WHERE 1",data,(err, results,) =>{
    !err ? res.json(results) : res.json(err)
  })
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
});

Что выводит 
Фронтенд component LogoBar:
import './LogoBar.scss'
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
export  const LogoBar =()=>{
//---------------------------------- Online -------------------------------
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('back4')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => setData(res.online))
    }, [])
    console.log(data)
    return(
        <div className="LogoBar">
            <div className="LogoBar_label"> Online:{data}</div>
        </div>
        )
}

Выводит: 
Пытаюсь в компоненте InfoBarShop вызвать LogoBar.data и сохранить в БД :
import './InfoBarShop.scss'
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { LogoBar } from '../../LogoBar1/LogoBar';
return(
        <div className="InfoBarShop">
            <div className="InfoBarShop1">
                <input className="InputMorphis" type='text' id='Morphis' name='Morp' min="0" max="500" placeholder='ammount'/>
            </div>
            <div className="InfoBarShop2">
                <div className="InfoBarShop22">DRC:21</div>
                <input className="InputAlphus" id="Alphus" type='text' name='Al' min="0" max="500" placeholder='ammount'/>
                <button className='buttons' onClick={postData}>Total</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
}
function getValues(){
    var inputMorphis = document.getElementById("Morphis").value
    inputMorphis = parseInt(inputMorphis)
//--------------------------- Alphus ---------------------------
    var inputAlpus = document.getElementById("Alphus").value
    var Alphus = parseInt(inputAlpus)
//--------------------------- Total ----------------------------
    let ggs = inputMorphis+Alphus
    return JSON.stringify(ggs);
}
let postData = () =>{
    const varss = LogoBar.data
    let fsfs = getValues() + varss
    let post = axios.post('http://localhost:3002/chatback',{
        Hunters: fsfs
    })
    console.log(fsfs)
}

В БД сохраняется только значение из getValues().

Надо к tOnline которая получена из БД(90) прибавить значение getValues() и только потом сохранить.
Структура файлов


Эм, const vars = data.online[0].tOnline?

Дело в том что если сделать online: results[0].tOnline все правильно выводится, но если попытаться к ней прибавить какое либо число в переменной допустим var abc = 39 console.log(vars+abc) выводит 39undefined

Пытаюсь к tOnline полученной из БД прибавить число из input поля и отправить post запросом в БД на сохранение. let post = axios.post('http://localhost:3002/chatback',{         Hunters: getValues() + LogoBar.vars     }) сохраняется только значение getValues(), а LogoBar.vars не прибавляется

ну так приведите к числу свой data.online[0].tOnline и используйте

@Arbery В смысле привести ? Я к data.online[0].tOnline и пытаюсь прибавить но не получается data.online[0].tOnline определяется как undefined именно тогда когда прибавляю число. Если вывести в лог только data.online[0].tOnline то покажет данные из БД

json это строка, текст если хотите, и вы к строке прибавляете строку вот и получается строка..

И что такое LogoBar?

Приветдите более полный пример кода, где вы получаете undefined. Но судя по комментариям, вы добавляете к полученному значению чтото, что не определено. Там может быть банальная опечака в имени переменной

@alexey-ten LogoBar это отдельный компонент где принимается запрос из сервера с ответом от БД const [data, setData] = useState(null)     useEffect(() => {         fetch('back4')         .then(res => res.json())         .then(res => setData(Number(res.online)))     }, []). Соответственно LogoBar.data это переменная data из Другого компонента который импоротировал.

@Резидент-Казахстана понимаю что из json получается строка в виде чисел, в этом и заключается вопрос: Как прибавить к этим числам строкового типа  тип данных number из input поля?

Переменная data внутри компонента (функции) это совсем не свойство data у LogoBar. Вам нужно изучить как в реакте передаются данные между компонентами.

@alexey-ten А простыми словами можно, то бы решить вопрос который стоит здесь? Понимаю что я не профи и не программист, хорошо сейчас попытаюсь сразу в LogoBar передать запрос на сохранение ничего не импортируя.

Вы показываете какую то середину кода мелкими частями, а проблема у вас вылезает где то дальше с другими переменными. Приведите более подробный пример, ОТРЕДАКТИРОВАВ ВОПРОС и ДОБАВЬТЕ ВСЮ ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНОСТЬ работы вашего кода и описание, где что идет не так, как вы ожидаете

Так... У вас в примере не указано, где находится InfoBarShop относительно компонента LogoBar, кто к кого родитель и так далее, это сильно затрудняет дать рекомендацию, как поправить. Однако, то что вы пытаетесь делать LogoBar.data - это так не работает. LogoBar во первых функция, во вторых Функциональный компонент React. Можно заставить LogoBar.data возвращать нужные данные, но это будет не правильно. Работа(обмен) с данными далжна происходить через пропсы или с помощью хранилищ Redux или useContext. document.getElementById вообще в коде React, по хорошему, быть не должно.

@SwaD добавил уточнения

Картинка то мне зачем. Нужен код, где видно, как один компонент связан с другим. Нашел пару вопросов, как раз про передачу значений между компонентами первый, второй

Не мучаясь вызвал  const [data, setData] = useState(null)     useEffect(() => {         fetch('back4')         .then(res => res.json())         .then(res => setData(res.online))     }, [])     console.log(data) в итоге выводится как: getValues(допустим 50) + JSON.stringify(data). Лог: 9050, а должно быть 140

В итоге методом тыка и подбора стратегии выполнения кода получилось!
сначало data преобразовал как JSON.stringify(data) а дальше это значение провел через parseInt() оба значения и вуаля!
let postData = () =>{
    let fsfs = parseInt(getValues()) + parseInt(JSON.stringify(data))
    let post = axios.post('http://localhost:3002/chatback',{
        Hunters: fsfs
    })
    console.log(fsfs)
    console.log(data)
}

Тем у кого если будет такая же проблема: данные из сервера переведите в JSON.stringify() а дальше этот стрингфай пропустите через parseInt(), Можете вывести уже число куда хотите.

Если у кого то возникет такая же проблема, не пользуйтесь этим решением! Проверьте типы данных, приведите к числу там где надо это делать. parseInt(JSON.stringify(data)) число в строку и потом в число - Какой в этом смысл? А если data строка, то зачем ее в stringify'ить?

Без этого не работает и по этому если не переводить в строку, parseInt() выдает ошибку. Другого решения данной проблемы не нашел. Если есть кто сможет решить буду очень рад взглянуть на его способ. Ставите минуса не понятно за что. Я не отметил свой ответ как правильный, я лишь накидал вариант решения проблемы. Раз знатоки даже намеков на решение данной проблемы не дали, а лишь пишет и пишет что у меня мало знаний. Я же пришел узнать решение проблемы.

Потому что если делать правильно сразу и прислушиваться к советам, которые вам дают, то этой дичи в коде можно избежать.
